# mongodb. how map strings to integers from another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection with documents, for example:

```json
    [
        {
            'id':'1'
            'some_field':'test',
            'rates':[
                {'user_id':'12','rate':'very_good'},
                {'user_id':'13','rate':'very_good'}
                {'user_id':'14','rate':'bad'},
                {'user_id':'15','rate':'normal'}
    
            ]
        }
    ]
```

And i have collection with values of rates in string:

```json
    [
        {
            "rate_name" : "bad",
            "rate_value" : 1
        },
        {
            "rate_name" : "normal",
            "rate_value" : 2
        },
        {
            "rate_name" : "very_good",
            "rate_value" : 3
        },
    ]
```

I need map data from first collection from array rates with value from second collection and group this values to new field.

For example:

```json
    [
        {
            'id':'1'
            'some_field':'test',
            'rates':[3,3,1,2]
            ]
        }
    ]
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it if `"$getField"` is available (MongoDB server version 5.0 and above).  See  below for another option.

```js
db.ratings.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ratingScale",
      "as": "ratingScale",
      "pipeline": []
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rates": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$rates",
          "as": "rate",
          "in": {
            "$getField": {
              "field": "rate_value",
              "input": {
                "$first": {
                  "$filter": {
                    "input": "$ratingScale",
                    "as": "nameValue",
                    "cond": {"$eq": ["$$rate.rate", "$$nameValue.rate_name"]}
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": "ratingScale"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9uAXrBTa83T).

If `"$getField"` is unavailable, here's another way you could do it.

```js
db.ratings.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "ratingScale",
      "as": "ratingScale",
      "pipeline": []
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rates": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$rates",
          "as": "rate",
          "in": {
            "$first": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$ratingScale",
                "as": "nameValue",
                "cond": {"$eq": ["$$rate.rate", "$$nameValue.rate_name"]}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rates": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$rates",
          "as": "rate",
          "in": "$$rate.rate_value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unset": "ratingScale"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GwJ-o3p8jv-).

Comment: I have mongo v4.2.6 :( $getField not support by this version of mongodb

Comment: @MrOldSir  I added another option that doesn't use `"$getField"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a plain `$unwind` then `$lookup` approach.

```js
db.col1.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$rates"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "col2",
      "localField": "rates.rate",
      "foreignField": "rate_name",
      "as": "rates"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$rates"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      some_field: {
        $first: "$some_field"
      },
      rates: {
        $push: "$rates.rate_value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pd7Xtkb6LC6)