# Get the previous month document in mongoDB using mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to get previous month data using mongoose in MongoDB. Actually I am not getting proper solution. If current month is November, then I need October (previous) month's data. If current month is December then I need November month's data. How can I sort using mongoose.

```
db.find({
   ...Here I need to define month
)}
```

Please remember I need last month data only, not last 30 days data.

I have a example-

```
const current = new Date();
var lastMonth = new Date();
lastMonth.setMonth(lastMonth.getMonth() - 1);
const income = await this.incomeModel.find({
    createdAt: {
        $gte: new Date(lastMonth),
        $lte: current
    }
});
```

This example gives me last 30 days data. But I need last month data.

Here are two documents-

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "635e4156ffcee58387c0589e"
  },
  "seller": {
    "$oid": "635ce812583711421229422d"
  },
  "user": {
    "$oid": "635ce77e5837114212294222"
  },
  "address": {
    "$oid": "6353aaf0fa6a1b0124c22532"
  },
  "orderId": {
    "$oid": "635e309f70a314e09df4c9ed"
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": {
        "$oid": "635cee1bf0a34d127f5403a6"
      },
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ],
  "income": 850,
  "paySuccess": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1666257494398"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667136287762"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "refunded": "Cancelled"
}
```

This is created on 20 October 2022,

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "635e416effcee58387c058a7"
  },
  "seller": {
    "$oid": "635ce812583711421229422d"
  },
  "user": {
    "$oid": "635ce77e5837114212294222"
  },
  "address": {
    "$oid": "6353aaf0fa6a1b0124c22532"
  },
  "orderId": {
    "$oid": "635e30e170a314e09df4c9f6"
  },
  "products": [
    {
      "productId": {
        "$oid": "635cee33f0a34d127f5403b0"
      },
      "quantity": 2
    }
  ],
  "income": 850,
  "paySuccess": true,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667467118696"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1667481887762"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Another document created on 03 November 2022

Now I need to get last month data only. As from two documents, the first one is created on last month, I need to find the first one document only.

Comment: "*f current month is November, then I need September (previous) month's data*" - do you mean October? It would be helpful for your to add sample json documents and the excepted output to demonstrate the expected behaviour

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that. I updated my question. That was a mistake.

Comment: I mean sample json documents. The json inside your MongoDB. Here is [one random question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74237810/mongodb-how-map-strings-to-integers-from-another-collection) I fetch from the community. Reference the way that they provide sample json documents.

Comment: @ray, I again updated my questions. Now, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$dateDiff` to compute the date difference with `$$NOW` in month unit. Get it with `$eq` to get the last month data.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      1,
      {
        "$dateDiff": {
          "startDate": "$createdAt",
          "endDate": "$$NOW",
          "unit": "month"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RFEILwSuDlB)